# XAML Grid.ColumnSpan to the left side

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a grid with 3 Columns and in Column 3 i have a rectangle which is to big for ist Column. but I want it in this Column so my question is is there a way to make Grid.ColumnSpan to the left side?

Comment: There is no way to make the columnspan go to the left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default there is no way to make Grid.ColumnSpan expand to the left. But there's an easy workaround: just implement the column span over the amount of columns needed, place the control in the leftmost cell and right-align. Add margin to the right side if necessary.

```
<Button Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Content="Hit me!" />
```

As you can see, I've created a grid with 3 columns (100px), added a button 1.5 times the column width and it visually 'overflows' to the left.

[image: Grid columns]

Comment: Thank you for your answer it just works perfectly fine! :)